# starting Android Device Monitor from Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to start Android device monitor from Android Studio, but I get this error message

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
>   must be available in order to run Monitor. No Java virtual machine
>   was found after searching the following locations:
>   /home/agusgambina/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/jre/bin/java
>   java in your current PATH

If in a terminal I execute

```
$ javac -version
```

I get this

```
javac 1.7.0_80
```

So I have declared the java compiler on the PATH, I don't know what I have to change to make it work

Thank you

Comment: What does executing "java -version" yield?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

@JamesWierzba thank you for asking

Answer (score 14, accepted):

go to your Android Studio JDK path (If you don't know then see it from File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs in android studio)

(in ubuntu it is normally /usr/local/jdk1.x.x)

inside jdk folder copy jre folder
and paste it to your android studio assuming path which is in your case
"/home/agusgambina/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/"

paste it inside monitor-x86_64 folder in sdk

Hope this will work!

Comment: Thank you @BhoomitBelani this was the solution, I tried and worked, I have to copy the jre folder inside the Android Sdk

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 7):

This problem had troubled me a long time.

I found a solution:

1. open termimal
2. `cd {you sdk home path}/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64`
3. `mkdir jre`
4. `cd jre`
5. `ln -s {you java home path}/bin bin`

To find your Java home path type:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

If nothing appears type: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

Actually， I just created a link to your Java home. But I am confused why Android Studio finds Java in this path.

Comment: I added JAvA_HOME to path, as suggested by other answers and that didn't work, so I think this is the best solution as it keeps the jre installed only in one place so you don't have to keep track of every java installation location when upgrading and also, you learn something about linux!

Comment: Much cleaner way of solving the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Look at your path environment variable (echo $PATH) to see where the OS is finding java.

Verify that the path to java is the same as the path that android-studio is assuming it to be. (/home/agusgambina/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/jre/bin/java in your case)

If they are not the same, you will have to tell android-studio the correct path to java. 
(I believe the option can be found at File->Other Settings->Default Project Structure->SDKs)

b.t.w.
javac is different from java

javac is the java compiler

java is the JVM exectuable (this is the one that is relevant in your problem)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was just 
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
then restart Android Studio and the Device Monitor worked

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file or edit the existing file called `.bash_profile` in your home directory:

E.g. `vi ~/.bash_profile`
Insert the following lines and adopt the paths to where your jdk is installed (probably it won't be `/home/anuradha/installs/jdk1.7.0_02`:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/anuradha/installs/jdk1.7.0_02
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/home/anuradha/installs/jdk1.7.0_02
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Source the `.bash_profile`, e.g. by calling `. ~/.bash_profile` or by opening a new terminal.

Check the java version by running `java -version`.

Answer (score -1):

You can make sure the location of the JRE in Project Structure UI which is in File menu. And then you just link the jre directory in  {you sdk home path}/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64.